# querying Google using google search API

Tags: php, xml, json, api, google-search

Google provides you a [way](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to add search functionality to your site through Google custom search, but is their any way that I can query Google in my PHP or JS code and get query result as a JSON or XML.
I am tagging php becuase may be some guy worked on it already
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but free package request is low(100 requests/day), you will have to purchase for more queries

Goto
https://console.developers.google.com
enable custom search api

Get the docs from here
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 0):

@user1765876: Just add &alt=json to the end of your request string.